# How can i pass the selected value as a parameter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can i pass parameter in jquery? first the function is runing on load window to check the value of selected item from `#id_oc_packages` if selected item is found in `#id_oc_packages` then execute `UpdateValue` function on load page this logic is working fine. Now i also want to run the function `updateValue` when i change the value from `#id_oc_package` change with my self. can anybody tell me how can do that?

I am getting this error`Uncaught TypeError: update.val is not a function`  when i try to change the value from `#id_oc_packages`

HTML

```
<select name="oc_packages" class="form-control" required="" id="id_oc_packages">
  <option value="">--------</option>
  <option value="oc" selected="">OC</option>
  <option value="vo">OC/VO</option>
  <option value="st">OC/SOT</option>
  <option value="vost">OC/VO/SOT</option>
  <option value="pkg">OC/PACkAGE</option>
</select>
```

jQuery.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        let update = $("#id_oc_packages");
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            UpdateValue(update);
        });

        function UpdateValue(update) {
            if (update) {
                if (update.val() == 'oc') {
                    $('#is_vo').hide();
                    $('#is_sot').hide();
                    $('#is_pkg').hide();
                    $('#is_voxpops').hide();
                    $('#id_oc').attr("rows", 16);
                }
                if (update.val() == 'vo') {
                    $('#is_sot').hide();
                    $('#is_pkg').hide();
                    $('#is_voxpops').hide();
                }
                if (update.val() == 'vost') {
                    $('#is_pkg').hide();
                    $('#is_voxpops').hide();
                }
                if (update.val() == 'pkg') {
                    $('#is_voxpops').hide();
                }
            }
        }
        
        $(update).change(function (e) {
            console.log($(this).val()) // this is working fine!

           // this funtion is not working it getting error!
            UpdateValue(update.val() = $(this).val());
        });
       
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```js
function UpdateValue(ocValue) {
    $('.packages').hide();
    if (ocValue != "") {                
        switch(ocValue) {
          case 'oc':
            $('#id_oc').show();
            break;
          case 'vo':
            $('#is_vo').show();
            break;
          case 'st':
            $('#is_sot').show();
            break;
          case 'vost':
            $('#is_voxpops').show();
            break;
          case 'pkg':
            $('#is_pkg').show();
            break;
          default:
            $('.packages').show();
        }                
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#id_oc_packages').change(function (e) {
    console.log($(this).val()) // this is working fine!

    // correction
    UpdateValue($(this).val());
  });     
  
  $("#id_oc_packages").change();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select name="oc_packages" class="form-control" required="" id="id_oc_packages">
  <option value="">--------</option>
  <option value="oc" selected>OC</option>
  <option value="vo">OC/VO</option>
  <option value="st">OC/SOT</option>
  <option value="vost">OC/VO/SOT</option>
  <option value="pkg">OC/PACkAGE</option>
  <option value="all">ALL</option>
</select>

<div class="packages" id="id_oc">OC Select</div>
<div class="packages" id="is_vo">OC/VO Select</div>
<div class="packages" id="is_sot">OC/SOT Select</div>
<div class="packages" id="is_voxpops">OC/VO/SOT Select</div>
<div class="packages" id="is_pkg">OC/PACkAGE Select</div>
```

Demo jsfiffle : https://jsfiddle.net/h0rko8fe/

Answer (score 0):

To get an element by id, the `#` character stands for id, which means you can get the element by getting `$("#oc_packages")`. jQuery looks for an element with an id of "id_oc_packages", and can't find it - thus not understanding the `.val` function.

Comment: the element id `#id_oc_packages` is woking fine with `updateValue` funtion. The issue getting with on change functon maybe i am not pass the right paremeter in on change function when i try to get the update.val() in console log the value is working fine

Comment: Sorry, I indeed missed the correct id of your input. However, it seems like your `UpdateValue` function expects `update` as argument, and you pass an expression, which might be causing the error. What exactly are you trying to achieve when you pass `update.val() = $(this).val()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`UpdateValue(update.val( $(this).val() ) );`

instead of it:

`UpdateValue(update.val() = $(this).val());`

According to this [ref](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp)

You must set value as example:

`$(selector).val(value)`

Answer (score 0):

You are making things unnecessarily complicated for yourself. jQuery is all about keeping things simple ...

```
$(function(){
 $("#id_oc_packages").change(
  function(){
   switch(this.value){
    case 'oc':
     $('#id_oc').attr("rows", 16);
     $('#is_vo').hide();
    case 'vo':
     $('#is_sot').hide();
    case 'vost':
     $('#is_pkg').hide();
    case 'pkg':
     $('#is_voxpops').hide();
   }
 }).change();
})
```

There is no need to explicitly define the function `UpdateValue()`. You can define the change event handler directly and trigger it immediately by calling the jQuery method `.change()` (without an argument).

I am uncertain whether the actions you are performing are sufficient: You are only hiding elements and never show them again...